# python from ['a','b','c','d'] to ['a', 'ab', abc', 'abcd']

Tags: python, list

I have a list `['a','b','c','d']`, want to make another list, like this: `['a', 'ab', abc', 'abcd']`?

Thanks

Tried:

```
list1=['a','b','c', 'd']
   
    for i in range(1, (len(list1)+1)):
        for j in range(1, 1+i):
            print(*[list1[j-1]], end = "")
        print()
```

returns:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
```

It does print what i want, but not sure,how to add it to a list to look like `['a', 'ab', abc', 'abcd']`

Answer (score 6):

Use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate), which by default sums up the elements for accumulation like a cumulative sum. Since addition (`__add__`) is defined for `str` and results in the concatenation of the strings

```
assert "a" + "b" == "ab"
```

we can use `accumulate` as is:

```
import itertools

list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

list2 = list(itertools.accumulate(list1)) # list() because accumulate returns an iterator

print(list2) # ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd']
```

Comment: I never thought about using `accumulate` with strings. That's a nice solution.

Comment: @Matthias I never had a use-case either, but you can encounter everything on SO. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Append to a second list in a loop:

```
list1=['a','b','c', 'd']
list2 = []
s = ''
for c in list1:
    s += c
    list2.append(s)
    
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd']
```

Comment: Just what i want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
list1=['a','b','c', 'd']
l = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    l.append("".join(list1[:i+1]))

print(l)
```

Printing stuff is useless if you want to do ANYTHING else with the data you are printing. Only use it when you actually want to display something to console.

Answer (score 1):

You could form a string and slice it in a list comprehension:

```
s = ''.join(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
out = [s[:i+1] for i, _ in enumerate(s)]
```

print(out):

```
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a list comprehension:

```
vals = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
res = [''.join(vals[:i+1]) for i, _ in enumerate(vals)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
[''.join(list1[:i+1]) for i,l in enumerate(list1)]
```

Output:

```
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd']
```